# QueryPerformanceCounter function's use on online judge

Tags: c++, time

Can I use `QueryPerformanceCounter()` on online judges or competitive programming websites like *codeforces, spoj* etc.? When I use it on *ideone* it shows the error:

```
"QueryPerformanceCounter was not declared in this scope".
```

If not then is there any other way to calculate an algorithm's running time except `clock_t`. I want to be more precise than that (something in the millisecond area or so).

Comment: [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) would probably come in handy. Check out the documentation on usage of [`std::chrono::duration_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast)

Comment: Thanks,paste same thing as answer so that i can accept it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QueryPerformanceCounter` is a Windows-specific API call, so on any system that uses a Window compiler behind the scenes it should probably work.

If they use a unix-based system, then depending on the flavor you may be able to use other options like `gethrtime` (At least Solaris), `clock_gettime`, `gettimeofday` and possibly others.

If you have access to C++11 then you also gain access to a more portable method in the form of `std::chrono`.